# Cannot Edit the Object Permission for Standard User Profile or for any Profile while logged in as System Administrator in Developer Sandbox

Tags: permissions, object

I am using Salesforce Developer Sandbox and created a custom object called candidate test. After creation I noticed that the Standard Profile "Standard User" does not have access to it. When I tried editing the Profile Object Permissions to add Read/Edit permissions to it, I saw that the whole of the Object permission is disabled not only for this profile but for almost all profiles. How do I make sure that I am able to enable the Object Permissions for all profiles.[image]

Answer (score 2):

You cannot edit the standard profiles in any org. You do have two options however:

1. Clone the profile and add the necessary permissions
2. Create a permission set and apply it to users who require the desired access

Answer (score 1):

Standard profiles can be cloned to create new profiles. Better create new one and assign users the new profiles.